# ajax insert to mysql issue

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I got a problem in ajax I can't add information on mysql so here's what I got:

a index.php file with a table form

```
<form  method="post" name="form" action="">
<textarea style="width:500px; font-size:14px; height:60px; font-weight:bold; resize:none;" name="content" id="content" ></textarea><br />
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" class="submit_button"/>
</form>
```

and a insert.php file:

```
<?php
include('config.php');


$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO chat(ChatId,ChatText) VALUES('','$content') ");
echo $content;

?>
```

I leave there the `echo $content;` because it helps to understand my problem. So... When i write something in my box and I click on submit to insert the information into my sql table It dosen't insert so I leave there the echo code because I'm sure the information reach to my insert.php file.. so I don't really understand why the information is not inserted because the information comes. Any help?

ajax part:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#ChatMessages").load("msgs.php");
    },1000);
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$(".submit_button").click(function() {
var textcontent = $("#content").val();
var dataString = 'content='+ textcontent;
if(textcontent=='')
{
alert("Enter some text..");
$("#content").focus();
}
else
{
$("#flash").show();
$("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "insert.php",
data: dataString,
cache: true,
success: function(html){
$("#show").after(html);
document.getElementById('content').value='';
$("#flash").hide();
$("#content").focus();
}  
});
}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is the ajax part?

Comment: Have you checked [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)?

Comment: It really counts the ajax part if I got the information in insert.php ? i edited my post i just put the ajax part

Comment: Put the whole sql statement into a variable and echo that variable instead of echo'ing the value of content.  Then copy/paste that sql statement into mysql command line - and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Please test this by hard-coding a value for $content in the PHP. My guess is your SQL is not executing properly. Are you sure you are connected to the database? Is that query being executed at all?

Comment: the include('config.php'); make the connection to database from insert.php 2 line but i add to print mysql error and say no database selected but in config.php i already did it

Comment: I found the problem the mysql query code is from old method and my config file has pdo method to connect. it always is something!!! thanks guys anyway.